# How to create a Design Automation workitem with a composite design Revit file with nested references

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

Given the following situation, where "->" is a Xref reference in either overlay or attachment mode:

TOPHOST.rvt -> LINKA.rvt -> LINKA1.rvt

I know that I can use [.../:version_id/relationships/refs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=references%20%5Bautodesk-designautomation%5D%20&s=6d22e047-64b2-440a-a0d5-ebd5c34f2d47) to retrieve references from TOPHOST.rvt, which includes the reference to LINKA.rvt.

I can repeat this with a query for LINKA.rvt, which will return the reference to LINKA1.rvt.

This way, I can gather all information necessary to [create a workitem](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/) for design automation, following [this guide on how to include links](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/) (see "Host RVT file with linked models").

This works for versions that are not marked as **isCompositeDesign** (not documented in [versions/:version_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/), but isCompositeDesign is a key in attributes.extension.data with boolean values). For these versions, the [.../:version_id/relationships/refs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=references%20%5Bautodesk-designautomation%5D%20&s=6d22e047-64b2-440a-a0d5-ebd5c34f2d47) API will return empty data, ie. no references!

This is a huge problem, as in active projects, items are `isCompositeDesign=true` most of the time.

How can I get the reference information necessary to create a Design Automation workitem in scenarios with composite designs?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Apr. 28, 2023**

It seems related to one known issue FDM-3977. I will update here once our engineering team gets back.

====================

If your target version urn shows that it's a composite design in its `attributes.extension.data.isCompositeDesign` like this one, according to [Why an RVT model is (sometimes) downloaded as ZIP from BIM 360](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Why-a-RVT-model-is-sometimes-downloaded-as-ZIP-from-BIM-360.html), then you should get a ZIP file that contains the host and all linked RVTs while downloading the host RVT file via [GET buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/XXXX.rvt](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/). Isn't it what you want?

```json
{
    "type": "versions",
    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.UTLEaKw?version=4",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "test.rvt",
        "displayName": "test.rvt",
//...
        "versionNumber": 4,
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
        "storageSize": 111297725,
        "fileType": "rvt",
        "extension": {
            "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "schema": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.1.0"
            },
            "data": {
                "modelVersion": 3,
                "isCompositeDesign": true,
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                "compositeParentFile": "test.rvt",
//..
                "modelType": "multiuser",
//..
                "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
                "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
                "revisionDisplayLabel": "4",
                "sourceFileName": "test.rvt",
                "conformingStatus": "NONE"
            }
        }
    },
    "relationships": {
//...
        "storage": {
            "data": {
                "type": "objects",
                "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/XXXX.rvt"
            },
            "meta": {
                "link": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/XXXX.rvt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eason, thank you for your response, but no, this is not what I need. I need a list of references, ie. a functioning  .../:version_id/relationships/refs API for composite designs.

Comment: Hi Kai,  after discussing it with my colleagues, it seems related to one known issue FDM-3977. I will give you updates once our engineering team gets back to me.